# All Pages in Site Have 404 Error

Tags: web-part, 404

I recently added a custom webpart, and all pages started giving me a 404 error (even the root). I can get to central administration, but I don't see any errors either there, or in the event viewer. I'm not sure where else to check for error messages. I tried going to the site using http://siteurl./?contents=1, (which I understand is supposed to disable webparts) but that's not working either.

Comment: Seems like the site doesn't exist anymore.. Or the URL is not correct, the obvious mistake I can see is the `.` at the end.. Instead of `http://siteurl./?contents=1` it should be `http://siteurl/?contents=1`

Comment: Is the IIS application pool started for the web app?

Comment: 404 is more about file does not exist...from central admin > application management > view all site collection...see if the site collection still listed there. also make sure the Content Database still accessible check from SQL server.

Comment: all of the site collections should be in that list? I've created several site collections, but the only one in that list is `/my` - My Site

Comment: from the manage Content Database section, make sure database attached to the web app, also check database from SQL server.

Comment: There's only one database attached to the web app, and only one site collection in that database. Would the sites be anywhere else?

Comment: looks like sites get deleted? all sites in one Content Db?

Comment: try to run the Get-SPDeletedSite and see if you can see the your sites

Comment: Are you able to load any other site?,  if not then check few things.  IIS, App Pools,  what does your custom web part does,  is it looking out for specific files (css, JS).  It might occur that your web part is looking for some files and failing all the site.

Answer (score 0):

The site may want to use a master page that is not where the page is looking for it.
To verify it, open the requested page in SharePoint Designer. If the master page is missing, it will give a more detailed error.

http://expectedexception.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/the-resource-cannot-be-found-http-404-error-in-sharepoint/

Comment: when I tried to open the root site, I got the error: "The URL 'sharepointsql/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll' is not contained within a Microsoft SharePoint Foundatation site."